# Django Dynamic URL from Forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

TL;DR - I failed implementing dynamic urls for too long.
My plan is:
Whenever the form is submitted, it would redirect you to a page (with a pk as the url), that sums up your choices.

I'm aware that this was asked multiple times and I was able to implement Dynamic URLs perfectly fine with a new project.
Yet, my current one is simply not making any sense to me.

I have a simple form with CharField as fields.
It renders them from the Models file which states pretty much the same.

I added to the Models.py:

```
> task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

The form is inside "hunting.html", and you access it through the navbar:

```
> <a class="nav-link {% if 'hunting' in segment %} active {% endif %}"  href="/hunting.html">
```

My view is quite simple, I recently opted to Class-based (when using function-base it did not work as well):

app/views.py

```
class Hunting(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = HuntForm()
        print('Access Hunting')
        return render(request, 'home/hunting.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HuntForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        name = request.POST['name']
        limit = request.POST['limit']
        os = request.POST.getlist('os')
        mal = request.POST.getlist('mal')
        my_type = request.POST.getlist('my_type')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('Hunt information is saved')
            return redirect('home/index.html')
        return redirect('home/index.html')
```

app/urls.py:

```
path('', views.index, name='home'),
path('hunting.html', views.Hunting.as_view(), name='hunting'),
# Matches any html file - this means that you only need to create a HTML page, and it registers it.
re_path(r'^.*\.*', views.pages, name='pages'),
```

What am I trying to do?:
Whenever the form is submitted, it would redirect you to a page (with a pk as the url), that sums up your choices.

I tried many solutions (I believe my implementation was wrong):

1:

- Created a URL:

```
path('hunting/<int:pk>', views.Hunting.as_view(), name='hunting-task'),
```

- Redirected my view towards the url 'hunting-task'.

2:

- Created separate view and HTML, this would request the user's confirmation for the form and then execute the separate view.
  Unfortunately, I got in so much mess that I reverted back.

3:

- Opting towards Class-based views, still failing to implement.

**Update:**
**4:**

- I created a URL:

  ```
    path('hunting/<int:pk>/', views.HuntTaskView.as_view(), name='hunt-task'),
  ```

I added a new View:

```
class HuntTaskView(DetailView):
form = HuntForm
template_name = 'task-view.html'
```

But whenever I submit the form, this is the error I receive:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'hunt-task' with arguments '(,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hunting/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Based on what you can see, is there a way to implement what I'm trying to do?

> What am I trying to do?:
> Whenever the form is submitted, it would redirect you to a page (with a pk as the url), that sums up your choices.

E.g:

1. User accessed 'hunting.html'.
2. User entered information in the form fields.
3. Details are passed onto a template with a dynamic url: "localhost:80/hunting/1"

Comment: Your first attempt might have been okay but it seems you used the same view for that url as the one handling the form, your second attempt is exactly what you need to do, create a separate view having a URL once the form is submitted just redirect to the other url.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - I might be missing something, but if I create a different view, whenever the user hits 'submit' from the form, he needs to be redirected to another url and confirm it, which will then run the view function I inteded to at first. Is that correct?

Comment: What? Wait you're doing all of this just to ask for confirmation? Just put the confirmation on the same page using some JavaScript and a modal or something, why make it so complicated?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - I am not, that's why I asked. 
I added a URL, a new View to work with it, but apparently I don't have any PK to assign to it, as I receive "Reverse for 'hunt-task' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hunting/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']" error.